# Visual Studio 2010 with .NET Framework 2

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

Sorry if this seems like a stupid question but can't find any info on it. I use Windows 7 and have Visual Studio 2010 as its free for students. Is it possible to write application in the .net frame work version 2 so I can also run these applications on Windows XP? Do I have to use an older version of Visual studio or a special way to compile?

Comment: small caveat; if you target 2.0 from VS2010 you are *actually* targetting 2.0SP2. Just watch out for that if you have 2.0 (vanilla) clients.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's possible.
You should choose ".NET Framework 2.0" in dropdown list on top of "New project" dialog screen.
Or you can change target framework of existing project in its properties dialog.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you are able to [target specific frameworks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398202.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Yes u can make project in `.net 2.0` too,
while creating project select `.net 2.0` from top right corner of create project dialog

Answer (score 1):

After the installation of the **3.5 framework**, you should be able to select the 2.0 framework as already mentioned